# How can i use sql database query?

Tags: android

Hello. I am new to android. In my application there is three tables category , product and quality in spinner. when i select perticular category , product related to that category would be display in product category. How can i do this? Please help me.

Comment: Will you provide more fields ?

Answer (score 1):

Manisha, I am assuming this database is local (sqlite3) and hence you would need to implement DatabaseHelper class.

Refer this tutorial for details

http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742